# How to execute files on local system using AWS Lamda Function

Tags: aws-lambda

I need to execute some Batch Files(.bat) stored on my local system from AWS Lambda Function.

Comment: For tips on asking a good question, please see: [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: What do you mean by "execute files on local system"? Do you mean your own computer? If so, you will need to run some software on your computer that accepts some form of connection from the Internet (eg API, web server).

Answer (score 0):

The easiest method to externally trigger some code to run on an Amazon EC2 instance is to use the [AWS Systems Manager Run Command - AWS Systems Manager](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/execute-remote-commands.html).

It needs an **agent** to be installed on the instance, and can then be used to execute commands on an EC2 instance, or even hundreds of instances, via an API call.

Comment: I don't think the question is asking about an EC2 instance